# Norm of a Matrix Vector Product : Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, vectors, matrix-norms

I'm trying to look for a concise proof for the inequality ||M.v|| ≤ ||M||.||v|| where v is a vector in R^n and M is a matrix with dimensions m*n.

I get the intuition behind what the inequality is saying I think. M is a transformation and it essentially represents how much it can "change" a vector. So if the norm of M is large, it can "change" v by a large amount.

So this inequality is saying that this new matrix Mv cannot "change" vectors by more than a factor of the size of M (||M||).

But my understanding is very abstract and I have  no idea how to go about the proof for it. I'm pretty sure the Cauchy Schwartz comes in here somewhere.

Comment: $\|M\| \hat{=} \sup_{v: |v| = 1} |Mv|$. So the inequality easily follows with this definition of $\|M\|$.